# Unable to upload a excel file from pc in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

[image]**Sel Java code for that Page I tried**

```
 WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("ddlEmailSource"));
        org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select se=new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select(element);
        se.selectByValue("ff");
        driver.findElement(By.id("div_btnFileUpload")).sendKeys("C:\Users\Phantom\Documents\1.txt");
```

**Error Details**`Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

HTML Code for that Page

```
<input title="Click to Select and Upload File" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; opacity: 0; top: 20px; left: 21px;" name="MyFile" type="file">
```

Also Tried with

```
driver.findElement(By.name("MyFile")).sendKeys("C:\Users\Phantom\Documents\1.txt");
```

But Also it throughs **Error Details**`Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Tried with

```
WebElement elementfile= driver.findElement(By.name("datafile"));
    elementfile.sendKeys("C:\Users\Phantom\Documents\1.txt");
```

Given error detail attached

Kindly give me suggestion what to do

Comment: why don't you try the forward slash '/' . It will work if you are providing the absolute path. Supports linux as well.

Comment: Hello All, While iam using "//" it doesnot through the compile ime error , but my objective still not getting fulfill , only the mycomputer opens and then thoughs a run tome error as follows ** (Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"datafile"}) ** , while my code is **driver.findElement(By.id("div_btnFileUpload")).click();

WebElement elementfile= driver.findElement(By.name("datafile"));
   elementfile.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt");**

Comment: looks like the identifier is incorrect, check the element can be identified using css or xpath

Comment: I have tried with **driver.findElement(By.id("div_btnFileUpload")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Docum‌​ents\\1.txt");** this too , but still not uploading , it line just doing nothing , my concern is previous code that after opening "My Computer" how to select a fille in **Windows** Platform

Comment: file upload via selenium is done in two ways 
1. **via sikuli or Autoit tool** = when a window pop up opens.(as in ur case)
2. **when the input tag with file upload should have the "type = file" attribute**
 then you can upload the file via sendKey directly .In your case its not working 
because the locator strategy that you used (id) is for 'Click to select and upload file' button. Please use input tag just behind that with 
'name = MyFile' then only it will work 'driver.findElement(By.name("MyFile")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt");'

Comment: Hi Rajnish Kumar Its getting uploaded by **driver.findElement(By.name("MyFile")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.tx‌​t");** , Thank you for help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just use `\\` and your code will work

```
WebElement elementfile= driver.findElement(By.name("datafile"));
    elementfile.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt");
```

Comment: Hello All, While iam using "\\" it doesnot through the compile ime error , but my objective still not getting fulfill , only the mycomputer opens and then thoughs a run tome error as follows ** (Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"datafile"}) ** , while my code is driver.findElement(By.id("div_btnFileUpload")).click(); WebElement elementfile= driver.findElement(By.name("datafile")); elementfile.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt")

Answer (score 0):

Use double backward slashes(`\\`) in path if you are using windows or use forward slashes if your are using linux or mac (`//`)

The better way is place your file and it's folder inside your project itself and You can also use path as below:-

```
./src\\Documents\\1.txt
```

OR

```
String testDataFile  = System.getProperty("user.dir"+"\\1.txt");
File src = new File(testDataFile)
```

`user.dir` will give you the location of current directory of project

It means your excel file should be present in the project folder itself. Create a folder in your project directory and paste this file inside that folder. This way git will also pushed that data to your repository and will going to locate by server as well.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hello All, While iam using "\\" it doesnot through the compile ime error , but my objective still not getting fulfill , only the mycomputer opens and then thoughs a run tome error as follows ** (Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"datafile"}) ** , while my code is driver.findElement(By.id("div_btnFileUpload")).click(); WebElement elementfile= driver.findElement(By.name("datafile")); elementfile.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt")

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hi Qa Testing plz update your last line of code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("div_btnFileUpload")).sendKeys("C:\Users\Phantom\Documents\1.txt");
```

to

```
driver.findElement(By.id("div_btnFileUpload")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt");
```

This will solve the issue you are facing.Also please note that in Java with selenium always use double slash "\\" .

update :

File upload in Selenium can done in two ways :

```
1. via sikuli or autoit tool (Basically windows automation tool).
2. direct upload when the tag has one attribute **type=file**
```

in your case you are trying to do file upload on a button and not on
tag with attribute **type=file** thats why a window pop up gets open every time 
when you run the above code. instead to do file upload simply do like below (as provided in your screenshot)

```
driver.findElement(By.name("MyFile")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt");
```

or if that does not work the use like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div_btnFileUpload']/input[2]")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt");
```

Hope this helps you now.

Comment: Hi Rajnish Kumar it throughs Compile time error , as uploaded the picz, that is  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: yes u are right it will give u compile time error not runtime error plz do update your path inside the sendKeys to this "C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt" and compile time error will fade away

Comment: Hello All, While iam using "\\" it doesnot through the compile ime error , but my objective still not getting fulfill , only the mycomputer opens and then thoughs a run tome error as follows ** (Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"datafile"}) ** , while my code is driver.findElement(By.id("div_btnFileUpload")).click(); WebElement elementfile= driver.findElement(By.name("datafile")); elementfile.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt")

Comment: you do not need to click on browse button or open any " mycomputer opens" window ... You just need to use sendkeys with the browse button

Comment: Hi Shubham Jain , I have tried with that too , but it reacts nothing check the code as follows **driver.findElement(By.id("div_btnFileUpload")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.txt");**

Comment: file upload via selenium is done in two ways 1. via sikuli or Autoit tool = when a window pop up opens.(as in ur case) 2. when the input tag with file upload should have the "type = file" attribute then you can upload the file via sendKey directly .In your case its not working because the locator strategy that you used (id) is for 'Click to select and upload file' button. Please use input tag just behind that with 'name = MyFile' then only it will work 'driver.findElement(By.name("MyFile")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Phantom\\Documents\\1.tx‌​t");' –

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party application [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to achieve this task.

Your AutoIt script should look like this

```
WinWaitActive("Choose File to Upload"); //File Upload is the dialog's title
Send("C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\filename.csv");
Send("{ENTER}");
```

Answer (score 0):

@QATesting - You can update your code as below:

It should work as it is working for me. And give your test method priority as per your requirement. Just for Example I gave priority here as @Test(priority = 1). I hope it should work for you.

```
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void CERTIFICATIONSSCREENUploadCertficationFilesValidation()
            throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        //Click on File Upload Button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='certificationFile']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // Set the file name in the clipboard. Also following line of code will search file in your computer so make sure you provide correct file path.

        StringSelection s = new StringSelection("C:\\Doc\\CertificationFile.xls");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(s, null);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Robot robot1 = new Robot();
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```